# Calculate Difference between Expectation and Conditional Expectation

Tags: statistics, expectation, conditional-expectation

Can $g(X) = \mathbb{E}[X | X>k] - E[X]$ be simplified as a single expectation as $[E | q(X)]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not totally clear to me what you are asking for but if

$$q(X)=\left(\dfrac{\mathbb I[X>k]}{\mathbb P (X>k)} -1 \right)X$$ where $\mathbb I[A]$ is an indicator function for an event and $\mathbb P (A)$ is the probability it is $1$,

then $g(X) = \mathbb E[q(X)]$